# upload - resend form - attach files - Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have in Symfony 1.4 form:

```
$this->setWidget('title', new sfWidgetFormInputText());
$this->setWidget('photo', new sfWidgetFormInputFile());
```

if i send this form, and he is valid then show me page with error. In input TITLE is previous text, which i entered, but no link to attach files. I must again search this file and select. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can't. This is a symptom of HTML file inputs.

A file input takes a the local path of the file on the client's machine (not the server), so consider this (hypothetical) scenario:

1. User A uploads a file and saves article
2. User B edits the article, and the file input is pre-populated with the path to the file that was uploaded by User A (but the path doesn't exist on User B's machine).
3. User B saves, and no file is submitted.

It would be a major security risk also. Let's say you write a malicious script which contains a form and file input. If you knew the path to a file on the client's machine then you could pre-populate the file input and then submit the form with JavaScript to force the user to upload the file.

This is why you can't pre-populate a file input in HTML.

As an alternative you should use `sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable` which will display the previously uploaded image alongside the file input. However, this will only display once the form has submitted and saved **successfully**.